# How to trap VK_ESCAPE in a listbox window proc

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, listbox

I have a custom grid control in a dialog that I want to popup a listbox to allow the user to select from a set of pre-defined values. I am unable to trap the VK_ESCAPE key, I have subclassed the control. I have tried WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR, WM_VKEYTOITEM with no success. I have the following styles set upon creation of the ListBox window (CreateWindow) WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_NOTIFY | WS_VSCROLL | LBS_WANTKEYBOARDINPUT. When the listbox is shown and esc is pressed, the key is passed to the dialog and it is processed as usual byt he dialog in that the dialog is canceled and closed. Any ideas where/how I can trap the VK_ESCAPE in the listbox window proc ? I already have a subclassed edit control that I do this with succesfully in grid control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to implement handling for the [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message in the window procedure for your control (that is; the control that you want to intercept the escape key - so in this case I think it would be your popup list rather than the grid control).

The dialog manager sends this message to the control with focus whenever a key is pressed and the return value can influence how the key is handled.

For example:

```
   case WM_GETDLGCODE:
      if (lParam)
      {
         LPMSG lpmsg = (LPMSG)lParam;
         if (lpmsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && lpmsg->wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
            return DLGC_WANTMESSAGE;
      }
      return 0;
```

If the control you're adding this to is not a custom control but e.g. is a system control, you'd need to sub-class it to add this handling.

Raymond Chen also has a [blog posting on this topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/26/55872.aspx).

Comment: Absolutely.. Thanks.. I also went through my edit control code (i did a while ago) and found the same !